# Android listview - Add a divider only at the end of the list

Tags: android, listview, divider

I'm creating a custom drawer view which has multiple listViews. To show this nicely to the user I want to separate these listViews with a divider.

I've managed to show the dividers between the items, and even get the last one to show a divider, but not just the last item.

I know I can toggle the dividers with

```
android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
```

But that is not the desired effect (dividers between each listitem). I just need a line underneath the list.

My ListView XML at this point:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list_view_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/progress_gray"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="#fff" />
```

Is there any way to achieve this effect?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I'm aware that I can put a view of 1dp height underneath the list. But I'm looking for an option within the list view. If that's not possible, which it's starting to look like. I'll go with that solution. Bit dirty in my opinion, but it can't be helped.

Comment: If you want to show divider after last item then set your listview's height to match_parent instead of wrap_content

Comment: This only works when you display the dividers, which renders them between all items. I want to only show one after the last item.

Comment: dela Croix : See my answer , i have provided solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add a 1dp high View between your listviews.

```
</ListView>
<View
   android:layout_height="1dp"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/red"
/>
```

Comment: I've considered that, though i'd like to keep it in the ListView, but I'm starting to doubt there is a way to achieve it.

Comment: You can set a background for the ListView, containing a line at the bottom. But in your case, I think a separate line is better, also from a logical perspective, as the line is not part of a listview but a separation between them.

Answer (score 0):

In your drawer layout add:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list_view_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="#fff" />
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/progress_gray"/>

<ListView android:id="@+id/list_view_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="#fff" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add view a the end of list using `addFooterView (View v)`. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View))

And looks like you will need to do this from code.

Answer (score 0):

For setting divider only at the last item of listview you can View or put horizontal line in imageview .

```
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageseprator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/strip" />
```

Or

```
     <View
        android:id="@+id/imageseprator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/strip"/>
```